# MySQL/PHP - change status depending on date

Tags: mysql, magento, teaser

I have a `MySQL Table`, let's say for blog posts. They have a column `status` which cam be active or inactive and two columns which are optional: `publish date` and `expire date` for scheduling posts.

Which solution do you recommend for changing the status depending on the publish date and expire date? Can I do this with a `PHP script` or `cronjob` ?

EDIT 30.11.16 / 16:50
Perhaps I have to be more precise about my specific problem: I have a `magento` store and I would like to add the possibility to schedule teasers. I want to change the existing code as little as possible.

Comment: Yes, a cronjob could do this, or decide the status when you're loading the content

Comment: When loading the content you could simply exclude any where the published date hasn't arrived or the expiry date has expired. That would save having to have a status update job. For the DB purists it might also be considered better database design - if the status is a field that can be determined purely based on the values in other fields, then it's effectively redundant since the value can be derived whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it depends, but as @ADyson sad you should't only work with a cronjob, because it show some posts that should have been expired.

But you think about to write a single class/function that handle the status and expiration / publish date logic. It will be a mess later, if you have the code copy in the cronjob and on different output pages.

I also would think about the status field, maybe it is not necessary, if you make some MySQL Selects like

```
...
WHERE publish_date>now() AND expire_date<now()
```